# Audio encoding using avcodec_fill_audio_frame() and memory leaks

Tags: ffmpeg

As a part of encoding decoded audio packets, I'm using avcodec_fill_audio_frame(). I'm passing allocated AVFrame pointer to along with buffer containing the decoded samples and other parameters number of channels, sample format, buffer size. Though the encoding is working fine I'm not able to completely eliminate the memory leaks. I've taken care of most of things but still I'm not able detect the leakage. 
Below is the function which I'm using for encoding. Please suggest something. 
AudioSample contains decoded data and it is completely managed in different class(free in class destructor). I'm freeing the AVFrame in FFmpegEncoder destructor and AVPacket is freed every time using av_free_packet() with av_packet_destruct enabled. What more do I need to free?

```
void FfmpegEncoder::WriteAudioSample(AudioSample *audS) 
{ 


    int num_audio_frame = 0; 
    AVCodecContext *c = NULL; 
   // AVFrame *frame; 
    AVPacket pkt; 

    av_init_packet(&pkt); 
    pkt.destruct = av_destruct_packet; 
    pkt.data = NULL; 
    pkt.size = 0; 
    int ret = 0, got_packet = 0; 
    c = m_out_aud_strm->codec; 
     static int64_t aud_pts_in = -1; 

    if((audS != NULL) && (audS->GetSampleLength() > 0) ) 
    { 
        int byte_per_sample = av_get_bytes_per_sample(c->sample_fmt); 

        PRINT_VAL("Byte Per Sample ", byte_per_sample) 
        m_frame->nb_samples = (audS->GetSampleLength())/(c->channels*av_get_bytes_per_sample(c->sample_fmt)); 
        if(m_frame->nb_samples == c->frame_size) 
        {   

#if 1 
        if(m_need_resample && (c->channels >= 2)) 
           { 
               uint8_t * t_buff1 = new uint8_t[audS->GetSampleLength()]; 
               if(t_buff1 != NULL) 
                { 
                     for(int64_t i = 0; i< m_frame->nb_samples; i++) 
                    { 
                        memcpy(t_buff1 + i*byte_per_sample, (uint8_t*)((uint8_t*)audS->GetAudioSampleData() + i*byte_per_sample*c->channels), byte_per_sample); 
                        memcpy(t_buff1 + (audS->GetSampleLength())/2 + i*byte_per_sample, (uint8_t*)((uint8_t*)audS->GetAudioSampleData() + i*byte_per_sample*c->channels+ byte_per_sample), byte_per_sample); 
                    } 
                    audS->FillAudioSample(t_buff1, audS->GetSampleLength()); 
                    delete[] t_buff1; 
                } 
            } 
#endif 
            ret = avcodec_fill_audio_frame(m_frame, c->channels, c->sample_fmt, (uint8_t*)audS->GetAudioSampleData(),m_frame->nb_samples*byte_per_sample*c->channels, 0); 
            //ret = avcodec_fill_audio_frame(&frame, c->channels, c->sample_fmt, t_buff,frame.nb_samples*byte_per_sample*c->channels, 0); 
            if(ret != 0) 
            { 
                PRINT_MSG("Avcodec Fill Audio Failed ") 
            } 
            else 
            { 
                got_packet = 0; 
                ret = avcodec_encode_audio2(c, &pkt, m_frame, &got_packet); 
                if(ret < 0 || got_packet == 0) 
                { 
                    PRINT_MSG("failed to encode audio ")     
                } 
                else 
                { 
                    PRINT_MSG("Audio Packet Encoded "); 
                    aud_pts_in++; 
                    pkt.pts = aud_pts_in; 
                    pkt.dts = pkt.pts; 
                    pkt.stream_index = m_out_aud_strm->index; 

                    ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(oc, &pkt); 
                    if(ret != 0) 
                    { 
                        PRINT_MSG("Error Write Audio PKT ")     
                    } 
                    else 
                    { 
                        PRINT_MSG("Audio PKT Writen ")     
                    } 
                } 
             } 
        } 
        avcodec_flush_buffers(c); 
     //   avcodec_free_frame(&frame); 
     } 

     av_free_packet(&pkt); 
}
```

Thanks,
Pradeep

Answer (score 1):

```
    //================== SEND AUDIO OUTPUT =======================
void AVOutputStream::sendAudioOutput (AVFrame* inputFrame)
{
      AVCodecContext *codecCtx = pOutputAudioStream->codec;

        // set source data variables
        sourceNumberOfChannels = inputFrame->channels;
        sourceChannelLayout  = inputFrame->channel_layout;
        sourceSampleRate = inputFrame->sample_rate;
        _sourceSampleFormat = (AVSampleFormat)inputFrame->format;
        sourceNumberOfSamples = inputFrame->nb_samples;


        // set destination data variables
        destinationNumberOfChannels = codecCtx->channels;
        destinationChannelLayout = codecCtx->channel_layout;
        destinationSampleRate = codecCtx->sample_rate;
        destinationSampleFormat =  codecCtx->sample_fmt;//AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTP;//EncodecCtx->sample_fmt;
        destinationLineSize = 0;
        destinationData = NULL;

        int returnVal = 0;


        if (startDecode == false)
        {
                startDecode = true;

                resamplerCtx = swr_alloc_set_opts(NULL,
                                                destinationChannelLayout,
                                                destinationSampleFormat,
                                                destinationSampleRate,
                                                sourceChannelLayout,
                                                _sourceSampleFormat,
                                                sourceSampleRate,
                                                0,
                                                NULL);


                if (resamplerCtx == NULL)
                {

                            std::cout <<  "Unable to create the resampler context for the audio frame";
                            isConnected = false;
                }


                // initialize the resampling context
                returnVal = swr_init(resamplerCtx);


                if (returnVal < 0)
                {
                        std::cout <<  "Unable to init the resampler context, error:";
                        isConnected = false;
                }


        } //if (startDecode == false)


        if (sourceSampleRate != 0)
                destinationNumberOfSamples = destinationSampleRate/sourceSampleRate * sourceNumberOfSamples;


        // allocate the destination samples buffer
        returnVal = av_samples_alloc_array_and_samples(&destinationData,
                                                       &destinationLineSize,
                                                       destinationNumberOfChannels,
                                                       destinationNumberOfSamples,
                                                       destinationSampleFormat,
                                                       0);



        if (returnVal < 0)
        {
                std::cout << "Unable to allocate destination samples, error";
                isConnected = false;
        }


        // convert to destination format
        returnVal = swr_convert(resamplerCtx,
                                destinationData,
                                destinationNumberOfSamples,
                                (const uint8_t **)inputFrame->data,     //sourceData,
                                sourceNumberOfSamples);


        if (returnVal < 0)
        {

                std::cout << "Resampling failed, error \n";
                isConnected = false;
        }


        int bufferSize = av_samples_get_buffer_size(&destinationLineSize,
                                                    destinationNumberOfChannels,
                                                    destinationNumberOfSamples,
                                                    destinationSampleFormat,
                                                    0);
        //whithout fifo
                                    pOutputAudioFrame  = av_frame_alloc();

                                    pOutputAudioFrame->nb_samples = codecCtx->frame_size;//frameNumberOfSamples;
                                    pOutputAudioFrame->format = codecCtx->sample_fmt;
                                    pOutputAudioFrame->channel_layout = codecCtx->channel_layout;
                                    pOutputAudioFrame->channels = codecCtx->channels;
                                    pOutputAudioFrame->sample_rate = codecCtx->sample_rate;


                                    returnVal = avcodec_fill_audio_frame(pOutputAudioFrame,
                                                                        pOutputAudioFrame->channels,
                                                                        (AVSampleFormat)pOutputAudioFrame->format,
                                                                        (const uint8_t *)destinationData[0],
                                                                        bufferSize,0);


                                    pOutputAudioFrame->pts = inputFrame->pts;



            if (returnVal < 0)
            {

                                std::cout << "Unable to fill the audio frame wsampleIndexith captured audio data,error";
                                isConnected = false;

            }




                        // encode the audio frame, fill a packet for streaming
                        av_init_packet(&outAudioPacket);
                        outAudioPacket.data = NULL;
                        outAudioPacket.size = 0;
                        outAudioPacket.dts = outAudioPacket.pts = 0;
                        int gotPacket;



                        // encoding
                        returnVal = avcodec_encode_audio2(codecCtx, &outAudioPacket, pOutputAudioFrame, &gotPacket);


                    // free buffers
                              av_freep(&destinationData[0]);
                      av_freep(&destinationData);
                          av_frame_free(&pOutputAudioFrame);



                        if (gotPacket)
                        {


                                outAudioPacket.stream_index = pOutputAudioStream->index;
                                outAudioPacket.flags |= AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY;

                                returnVal = av_interleaved_write_frame(pOutputFormatCtx, &outAudioPacket);
                                //returnVal = av_write_frame(pOutputFormatCtx, &outAudioPacket);





                                if (returnVal != 0)
                                {

                                        std::cout << "Cannot write audio packet \n";
                                        isConnected = false;
                                }

                        av_free_packet(&outAudioPacket);

                        } // if (gotPacket)



            }
```

You can see after resample i free used buffers.
 // free buffers
                    av_freep(&destinationData[0]);
                    av_freep(&destinationData);